# For which orthogonal $2\times2$ matrices does the exponential become orthogonal?

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $ A$ be a $2\times2$ real orthogonal matrix. Then when does $e^A$ become orthogonal as well? According to my calculations, $A$ must be skew-symmetric also and therefore there are only two possibilities. Am I correct?

Edit~~~
Ok, the two matrices are $\pmatrix{0 &1 \\ -1 &0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 &0}$. Thank you all for the advice below. Now, are these matrices correct? I think they are, but I would like others to check in case I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

That does indeed sound correct. (And you can probably generalize fairly easily to higher dimensions.)

As a general principle, it's worth knowing that the tangent space to the orthogonal group at $I$ consists exactly of skew-symmetric matrices; since $A \mapsto \exp A$ sends this tangent space to the orthogonal group (and indeed, ignoring speed for the moment, $t \mapsto \exp(tA)$ is a geodesic through the identity, for any skew-symmetric $A$), there's a pretty strong correspondence between the two.

Comment: Could you pleae show me the two matrices? I actually am not familiar with writing matrices on the latex so...I would like to check my answers are indeed correct.

Comment: To write the identity matrix, you type `\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}` and get $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$; more generally, `\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}` gives $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$. To answer your question: no, I won't write out the two matrices for you. That's a good exercise for you.

Comment: @Keith See  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023/588038) if you want to write a matrix using MathJax.

Comment: @JohnHughes OK, thanks to your advice, I wrote those matrices; it seems easier than I thought. Now, are they correct?